# Сравнить два JSON по значениям

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть несколько JSON которые хранятся у меня локально:

```
{'name':'Ivan', 'surname':'Petrov', 'position':'director'},
{'name':'Petr', 'surname':'Sidorov', 'position':'manager'},
{'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'driver'}
```

нужно их сравнить с JSON, которые я получаю с сервера (используя Python) по КАЖДОМУ значению. Они обычно совпадают с локальными значениями, но например если Yan Vlasov сменит должность на accountant, мне нужно узнать об этом и изменить локальный JSON (вручную). Как мне сравнивать каждый JSON с сервера с локадьными JSON по значениям? Пока на ум приходят только костыли аля переводить каждый JSON в строку `str({'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'driver'})` и сравнивать как строки, но это точно костыль.

Comment: нужно переводить не в строку, а словарь. Да и зачем переводить джейсон в строку, если он уже и есть строка.

Comment: Можете посмотреть еще в сторону уже готовых модулей для сравнения json, задача то сама далеко не новая: jsondiff, json_delta, deepdiff. Сам синтаксис сравнения у них всех простой: `differences = diff(json1, json2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется в виду что-то такое?

```
dict1 = [{'name':'Ivan', 'surname':'Petrov', 'position':'director'}, {'name':'Petr', 'surname':'Sidorov', 'position':'manager'}, {'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'driver'}]
# исходный лист json объектов

dict2 = {'name':'Petr', 'surname':'Sidorov', 'position':'manager'}
# искомый json объект

for d in dict1:
    if d == dict2:
        print('found')
        break
```

---

Из задачи понимаю, что у вас вот `Yan Vlasov` который работает `driver` принимает позицию `accountant`. В `Dict2` сложим актуальную информацию по `Yan Vlasov`, а далее используем его `name` и `surname` для того чтобы найти его в `dict1`. При этом условие должно выглядеть так, что `name` и `surname` совпадают, а `position` точно не совпадает. Тогда так

```
dict1 = [{'name':'Ivan', 'surname':'Petrov', 'position':'director'}, {'name':'Petr', 'surname':'Sidorov', 'position':'manager'}, {'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'driver'}]

dict2 = {'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'accountant'}

for d in dict1:
    if d['name'] == dict2['name'] and d['surname'] == dict2['surname'] and d['position'] != dict2['position']:
        print('found')
        break
```

---

И да, я представляю что ваш json изначально может выглядеть так, запрашиваясь сервера

```
{
  "data": [
    { "name": "Ivan", "surname": "Petrov", "position": "director" },
    { "name": "Petr", "surname": "Sidorov", "position": "manager" },
    { "name": "Yan", "surname": "Vlasov", "position": "driver" }
  ]
}
```

Но у меня это файл, поэтому я изображу по своему

```
import json

# Открываем файл data.json и читаем его содержимое, но в вашем случае это может быть request
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Извлекаем данные и преобразуем их в нужный формат
dict1 = data['data']

# Теперь переменная dict1 содержит нужный нам список словарей
print(dict1)

dict2 = {'name':'Yan', 'surname':'Vlasov', 'position':'accountant'}

for d in dict1:
    if d['name'] == dict2['name'] and d['surname'] == dict2['surname'] and d['position'] != dict2['position']:
        print('found')
        break
```

---

**UPD от комментариев**

может что-то тогда такое. Это будет работать при условии что у вас `name` и `surname` всегда уникальные, то бишь в вашем контексте нету тёсок. Мы используем `name` и `surname` как идентификаторы наших позиций, сверяем равны ли в принципе наши словари между собой, это сразу проверит на новые параметры и на разность существующих.

```
for d in dict1:
    if d['name'] == dict2['name'] and d['surname'] == dict2['surname']:
        if d != dict2:
            print('found')
            break
```

Comment: да работать будет для текущего примера, но если например в обе базы добавится допустим значение 'salary' то все сломается.
Вижу в идеале решение такое: брать для каждого JSON с локальноый базы фамилию, искать по всем значениям фамилии в JSON полученном с сервера. если совпало- брать каждую пару наименование:значение и сравнивать между собой. Тогда, если в базу добавится какое то новое наименование, то код не надо будет переделывать каждый раз

Comment: @babyborn да, это повлияет на работу первого примера, но в последующих, работая напрямую с ключами, мы продолжаем работать как прежде

Comment: @babyborn следовательно имеет смысл вести идентифицирующее поле, в контексте этого примера это `name` и `surname`

Comment: @babyborn я правильно понимаю, что вот у каждого `name` и `surname` может быть бесконечное количество параметров, которые могут изменяться, так?

Comment: дополнил коммент

Comment: да, имя и фамилтя- постоянные и не меняющиеся никогда, остальные параметры могут добавляться-удаляться

Comment: @babyborn обновил ответ

Comment: @babyborn в данном примере я поставил оператор `!=` неравенства, что как бы говорю, исполняйте код в случаях когда позиции все же не равны между собой, именно в этот момент вам нужно актуализировать локальные данные данными с сервера.